# Prevent UIButtons action running more than once

Tags: php, mysql, ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a **UIButton** setup on a **view** in storyboard and linked to an action.  The action runs some code that calls a PHP page (which in turn logs a record in a MySql DB) via NSURLSessionDataTask.

When I touch the button once and see log print out in the Log screen within XCode I can see my printed message once but if I check the MySql DQ I can see multiple identical records inserted.

I thought at first that maybe it was the PHP code but if I load the php page directly via a web browser I do not get the issue, only when running via ios code.

Is there anyway to stop a buttons code being executed more than?

Code from UIButtons action:

```
- (void)UpdateActions{

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxx/mobilescript/setactions.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

    NSString *postString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"imgname=%@",imageName];
    NSString *clearPost = [postString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"var=" withString:@""];

    [request setHTTPBody:[clearPost dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setValue:clearPost forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

     NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        NSString * returnStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",returnStr);
    }];
    [task resume];
}
```

Code from PHP:

```
<?php
    include_once("DB_SETTING.php"); //Includes DB settings

    $DB_HANDLE = mysql_connect( "$DB_SERVER" , "$DB_USERNAME" , "$DB_PASSWORD" ) or $errors[] = mysql_error();
    if(!mysql_select_db( "$DB_NAME" ))
    {
        $errors[] = "Unable to select database $DB_NAME";
    } 

    if($errors){
        echo '<pre>';
        foreach($errors as $result) {
            echo $result . ' <br>';
        }
        echo '</pre>';
    }

    //Check all settings are in place
    if(!isset($_REQUEST["imgname"]) )
    {
        echo("-1");
    }
    else
    {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO  `WS_ACTIONS` (  `ID` ,  `imgid` ,`memberid` ) 

                    SELECT 0,tb3.id,tb2.id FROM  WS_MEMBERS tb2,WS_IMAGES tb3 WHERE `IMGNAME` = '".$_REQUEST["imgname"]."' and tb2.email = '".$_REQUEST["email"]."' And NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 
                tb1.ID 
            FROM 
                WS_ACTIONS tb1 
            inner join 
                WS_IMAGES tb2 
            on 
                tb2.id = tb1.imgid
            inner join 
                WS_MEMBERS tb3
            on 
                tb3.id = tb1.memberid
            where 
                imgname = '".$_REQUEST["imgname"]."' 
            and 
                tb3.email = '".$_REQUEST["email"]."' 
            )";
            mysql_query($sql);
            echo($sql);
    }
?>
```

Comment: There is zero chance of anyone answering this without seeing your code. How do you expect us to answer this ?

Comment: How you read your response? Via delegate or with completion block?

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin - Code should be showing in the main question

Comment: @PanayotPanayotov - I am using a completion block to check the response

Comment: Are you saying that the button action runs more than once if you only touch the button once? If so, do you know this from putting a log in that method, or are you assuming based on getting multiple records?

Comment: @rdelmar - it's more of an assumption than an informed conclusion based not he fact I get the multiple records int he Sql DB and the fact I do not get the same behaviour direct through a desktop or mobile browser, only when using the button in-app.

Comment: You shouldn't assume. It's hard to fix a problem if you don't know its source. Put a log in the button method to make sure that it's not being called more than once per touch.

Comment: Only one output is displayed in the log, the assumption is based on the fact the button is the only way I can replicate the issue, web browsers do not do so.

Comment: Ok, so the problem isn't what you presume in your title -- it's not the button method running more than once, something is wrong with the method itself. Are you implementing the NSURLConnection delegate methods? You have the line, [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self] -- that starts a download, but you're also starting one with the NSURLSession. Try commenting out the line with the connectionWithRequest:delegate: call, and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @rdelmar - I had completely missed that, not sure how I managed to miss it.  I have done as you said and commented out NSURLConnection and it works exactly as expected.  Thank you so much to everyone for their help and especially to rdelmar for a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an instance of your button you can enable/disable it. Other solution would be creating a BOOL to hold whether the button should execute something or not

**Example:**

```
- (void)UpdateActions{

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxx/mobilescript/setactions.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

    NSString *postString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"imgname=%@",imageName];
    NSString *clearPost = [postString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"var=" withString:@""];

    [request setHTTPBody:[clearPost dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setValue:clearPost forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

     // disable your button if you have a reference to it
     [self.yourBtn setEnabled:NO]; // or set your BOOL to NO here
     NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
     // regardless of the response once your request had finished just enable your button again
        [self.yourBtn setEnabled:YES]; // or set your BOOL to YES here
        NSString * returnStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",returnStr);
    }];
    [task resume];
}
```

**EDIT**
You can try with `NSURLConnection` instead like this:

```
- (void)UpdateActions{

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxx/mobilescript/setactions.php"]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

        NSString *postString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"imgname=%@",imageName];
        NSString *clearPost = [postString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"var=" withString:@""];

        [request setHTTPBody:[clearPost dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [request setValue:clearPost forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

         // disable your button if you have a reference to it
         [self.yourBtn setEnabled:NO]; // or set your BOOL to NO here

         // create NSOperation to run your request on background
         NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
         // run your request on this peration queue
         [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request 
                                       queue:queue
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        NSString * returnStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"%@",returnStr);
         // do whatever you want with the response 

       [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        // Main thread work (UI usually)
        [self.yourBtn setEnabled:YES];
    }];

    }];

    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers, I still get the issues.  I've added more log outputs and a BOOL to try and stop the task being executed.  I have added code to disable the button and re-enable when complete.  Is it possible that its an issue with NSNSURLSessionDataTask?

Comment: Thanks Panayot, still same issue when using the button when swapping to NSURLConnection.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're starting two requests to your server. When you create a request with this line,

```
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

this starts a download from your server right away. Then, by creating an NSURLSessionDataTask with this line (then calling [task resume]), you start another download from your server,

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
```

If you're using the NSURLSession, you shouldn't also call connectionWithRequest:delegate:, so deleting that line should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you, I had completely missed that.  I think I did it as I migrated my code from NSURLConnection to NSURLSessionDataTask and missed some of the code to remove.  Thanks for your help.